# Windows 10 external screen no longer detected

Tags: windows-10, external-display, display-settings

I have an HP elitebook laptop. I work with an external screen that is from iiyama. This set up has worked perfectly fine for the last month or so (since I upgraded to windows 10 from windows 7).

Yesterday everything was fine, I finish work and head home. Today I get to work and the external screen doesn't seem to be working. I had a colleague test the screen, and with his machine it works perfectly fine.

The issue is that my laptop seems to be unable to detect the external screen.

I have tried various things already.

- All my display drivers are up to date.
- I tried troubleshooting for 'Hardware and devices'. Nothing comes up that has to do with the screen.
- I tried win+p et cetera to expand my screen to two screens. That doesn't work.
- When I go into my display settings I can see the second screen but it is black/grey -ed out. When I assign it to expand or duplicate to the second screen, I am unable to save and apply that configuration. It then prompts me to try a different combination of display settings.
- I'm not connected via a docking station but with a wire. The wire connects to a display port on the laptop side and to an HDMI port on the screen side.

Here are two screenshots of that:

Display settings screen:

[image: Display settings]

Prompt:

[image: Error prompt]

I assume windows 10 performed an update of sorts that now prevents me from detecting the screen, but I can't find a fix for it. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a docking station?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot about that. No, I'm connected via a display port on my laptop, through a cable that connects to a HDMI port on the screens back.

Comment: Check and see if it works with another HDMI to rule that out.

Comment: I had a collegua check it with the same cable, so I don't think it is the cable that is the issue.

Comment: Does your laptop have an integrated GPU ? Also check your laptop's display port for any physical damage.

Comment: Intel Graphics as far as  I know, but I also have some AMD drivers in the display section. Both are up to date. No damage I can see so far either.

Comment: The display settings also seem to know what kind of screen is attached, as they show the serial number name

Comment: Do you see the monitor in the control panel/graphics option from Intel Graphics or AMD? Open a CMD prompt and type in _dxdiag_. The Display tabs might show some more information about which driver is being used and the status. Going to Device Manager (right-click on start) > Monitors might also show more information. The issue seems strange, if you get the change, try a different monitor just to test it out.

Comment: The second monitor is managed by the AMD drivers. AMD Radeon HD 8750M

We have other screens, but we are all working now, so not really opportunity to test them. Perhaps this noon